# iOS: Parsing dictionaries from a string into NSMutableDictionary / NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parsing, dictionary

Is there a fast way to parse dictionaries in iOS from a sting, with the format:

```
property1: value1
property2: [ property3: value3 ; property4: [property5: value5] ]
property6: "and so on"
```

The string would contain something like:

```
NSString *str = @"property1: value1 property2: [ property3: value3 ; property4: [property5: value5]] property6: "and so on" ";
```

and would generate a root NSMutableDictionary / NSMutableArray element, containing additional 
NSMutableDictionary / NSMutableArray elements

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not using json format ?

```
replace this         with this
[                    {
]                    }
;                    ,
```

and you will be able to use jsonparser : NSJSONSerialization

Comment: sorry, replace what with what?

Comment: Those changes would not be sufficient to make this proper JSON.

Comment: Actually, converting the format I have into JSON is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. That isn't any standard format. It looks like a bizarro version of JSON. If you want to parse this format, you'll need to either find some third-party parser or wrote one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is invalid. Please use http://jsonlint.com to verity if your JSON string is valid or not. Now, given your JSON is valid, this is how you can read string JSON into a `NSDictionary`:

```
NSString *strData = @"{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":{\"property3\":\"value3\",\"property4\":\"value4\"}}";

NSData *data = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

Comment: You're assuming this is JSON. Your assumption is wrong.